# Adding the same paramaters to a list of functions in Elm

Tags: function, elm

The title says it all.
While I know that with List.map I am able to apply a function to a list of parameters, I would like to know if there is a workaround to send the same parameter to a list of functions.

I have done a bit of research and found nothing for now.

Comment: `List.map (\f -> f param) fs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just apply each function of the list to the passed param:

```
listOfFunctions : List (String -> String)
listOfFunctions = [(\x -> x ++ "1"), (\x -> x ++ "2"), (\x -> x ++ "3")]

apply : String -> List String
apply a = List.map (\f -> f a) listOfFunctions
```